# Set annotation's glyphtext based on the annotation's properties

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit, mkannotationview, reuseidentifier

I'm running into an issue with custom annotations displaying incorrectly. In my code, I check whether the current annotation is for a station with a given unique identifier. If so, I customize its properties.

**StationAnnotationView.swift**

```
class StationAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {

override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        guard let station = newValue as? Station else { return }

        clusteringIdentifier = nil
        displayPriority = .required

        if (station.id == "26") {
                glyphText = "p"
                markerTintColor = UIColor(named: "Blue")
        }
    }
}
```

At first, my `mapView` displays the annotations correctly (i.e., changing the color and glyphtext for the only station with `station.id == 26`), but after panning and zooming for a while, my custom formatting begins to get applied to other annotations (which shouldn't happen, because there's only one station for any given `station.id`). I suspect it's due to the `AnnotationView` reusing the annotation. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, it's due to the AnnotationView reusing the annotation. Try the following code:

```
    if (station.id == "26") {
            glyphText = "p"
            markerTintColor = UIColor(named: "Blue")
    } else {
            glyphText = // Default text
            markerTintColor = // Default color
    }
```

Comment: That solved it. I don't understand why, but it did. Thank you.